# ruby method to convert a hash to a string

Tags: ruby

please help me to make method named hash_string so that it takes the hash and make a string from its key/value pairs.
Example:

```
hash_string({id: 8, name: 'marry'}) # should return "id = 8, name = marry"
```

I've tried same way before,  they are:

```
def hash_string(hash)
  hash.to_s
end
```

and

```
def hash_string(hash)
  set_value = hash.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} = #{value}" }
  # set_value.join(",")
end
```

but they did not work. Will you please explain me, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `each` with `map`, return the value instead of outputting it, and you're done.

```
def hash_string(hash)
  set_value = hash.map {|key, value| "#{key} = #{value}" }
  set_value.join(",")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def hash_string(hash); hash.map{|e| e.join(" = ")}.join(", ") end
```

When `map` applies to a hash, `to_a` is applied, which gives key-value pairs. Each pair is captured by a single block variable `e`, to which `join` applies.

Comment: Sawa,thanks for your explanation. Now i clearly understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Is there another way? (You did ask.) I think this should work. Counterexample, anyone?

```
h = {:id=>8, name: "marry", "age"=>25, 7=>4}
  #=> {:id=>8, :name=>"marry", "age"=>25, 7=>4}

h.to_s[1..-2].gsub(/:?([^:]+?)=>/,'\1 = ').gsub('"', '')
  #=> "id = 8, name = marry, age = 25, 7 = 4"
```

- `h.to_s[1..-2]` converts the hash to a string and strips off the first (`{`) and last (`}`) characters.
- `:?` consumes a `:` if one is present immediately before the capture group that follows.
- `([^:]+?)` is capture group #1, which captures one or more characters other than `:`, non-greedily (signified by `?`) and is followed by `=>`.  Alternatively, one could have `/:?([^:=>]+)=>/`.
- The match, if there is one, is replaced by `'\1 = '`, which is the contents of the capture group, followed by `" = "`.  This could instead be written with double-quotes (`"\\1 = "`).

Let's walk through an example:

```
h = {:id=>8, "name"=>"mary"}             #=>  {:id=>8, "name"=>"mary"}
str0 = h.to_s                            #=> "{:id=>8, \"name\"=>\"mary\"}"
str1 = str0[1..-2]                       #=>  ":id=>8, \"name\"=>\"mary\""
str2 = str1.gsub(/:?([^:]+?)=>/,'\1 = ') #=>   "id = 8, \"name\" = \"mary\""
str2.gsub('"', '')                       #=>   "id = 8, name = mary"
```

Now let's have a closer look at the penultimate statement.

`gsub` is looking for substrings of:

```
":id=>8, \"name\"=>\"mary\""
```

that match the regex:

```
/:?([^:]+?)=>/
```

Whenever it finds one, it replaces it with `\1 =`, where `\1` denotes the contents of the regex's one and only capture group.

In `:?`, the `?` means "match a `:` if one is present. It finds one, before `id`. It now moves on to the "capture group" (capture group #1), designated by the parenthesis: `([^:]+?)`. `[^:]+?` captures one or more characters other than `:`.

As the capture group is followed by `=>`, it will capture matching characters until it reaches `=>`. But which pair, the one in `id=>8` or the one in `\"name\"=>\"mary\"`? Regex's are naturally "greedy", so if the capture group were `([^:]+)`, it would match the *last* one, capturing `id=>8, \"name\"`. To prevent that from happening, we add the `?` to make the match on `[^:]+?` "non-greedy", this is, stopped by the *first* `=>` it encounters, causing it to match just `id`.

`gsub` has matched `:id=>`, of which `id` is the contents of the capture group, which can be reference in a string by `\1`.  It therefore replaces `:id=>` with `\1 =` => `id =`.

Wait a minute.  The capture group does not match `:`, so why do we need `:?` at the beginning of the regex? Let's try without that:

```
str2 = str1.gsub(/([^:]+?)=>/,'\1 = ') #=> ":id = 8, \"name\" = \"mary\""
```

As you see, the first `:` was not removed.  That's because it was not part of the match that `gsub` replaced with `\1 =`. Hence the need for `:?`.

The last statement merely converts each `"` to an empty string (i.e., removes the double quotes).

Comment: Since you seem to be looking for a counterexample: `h = {"=>" => "foo"}` gives `" =  = foo"`.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, Although I've read the document [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-gsub), I did not understand that (.gsub) method . Would you please explain to me, how it works?

Comment: Rabby, your wish is my command. Note that the elaboration of my explanation is meant to give you a better understanding of how regex's work, and not so much about your question.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa. I figured there could be a few. I did not mean this to be a serious option (what I meant by "You did ask"), but thought it might have some educational value. I see `{ ":"=>"foo" } => " = foo"` is problematic as well.